# Editor in Quill trimming extra space

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I am using PrimeNG Quill `p-editor` in angular. By default, quill trimmed extra space. How can I preserve the extra space in editor in quill?

E.g. - model binding property - text = "  Hi I am Angular"

Output in editor - "Hi I am Angular"

expected in editor - "  Hi I am Angular"

---

Example of full text :

```
<p>Data &amp; control</p><ul><li>Comply with Our Code, How do we manage business </li><li>Provide proactive identification and effective management and/or escalation of conduct risk to deliver key customer outcomes</li><li>Own, manage and supervise risks within the business area, ensuring mechanisms are in place to identify</li><li>Ensure risk practices and behaviour are consistent with the target risk culture where work collaboratively with others</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use quill parameter preserveWhitespace.
set preserveWhitespace to true.

```
<quill-editro [preserveWhitespace]="true"> </quill-editor>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's maybe an option in Quill configuration but if not, you can replace spaces in front of your string model with `&nbsp;` :

```
this.text = "<p>   Desk Strategist </p><ul><li>  value 1</li><li>Value 2   </li><li> Value 3</li><li></ul>";
this.text = this.text.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rzY3l1P2478dRUzpXJuV?p=preview)

Comment: Check my new Plunker

Comment: I don't know...but this value is not working "<p>Desk Strategist </p><ul><li>value 1</li><li>Value 2 </li><li>  Value 3</li><li></ul>"

Comment: but after strategist..I have..actually problem is with extra space (more than 1 space at a same place). I have seen in quill, they put condition that if white-space is not starts with 'pre' then trim each node space. I tried to put style with white-space: pre-wrap in the html, but header style gets disturbed. Do you any solution over there?

Comment: Ok so just replace any space character with `&nbsp;` and it should be ok (see my new Plunker version)

Comment: it doesn't seems to be so simple...I tried with given input value 
 but formatting not working correcly, please try with it "<p>Data &amp; control</p><ul><li>Comply with Our Code, How do we manage business </li><li>Provide proactive identification and effective management and/or escalation of conduct risk to deliver key customer outcomes</li><li>Own, manage and supervise risks within the business area, ensuring mechanisms are in place to identify</li><li>Ensure risk practices and behaviour are consistent with the target risk culture where work collaboratively with others</li></ul>". Any help?

Comment: Next time, post directly the full example in your first message. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on

```
.ql-editor {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

copied from https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1752#issuecomment-428407357